# How to connect a D3 ODBC DB with PHP

Tags: php, database, odbc, pick

I have PICK.
I have a D3 ODBC Driver installed on my computer.
I would like to use PHP to access to the Date Base.

But i don't know how to use odbc_connect to connect my PHP server (WAMP) with ODBC.

For the moment i have this (not real info)

```
$connect_string = "Driver={D3 ODBC Driver};" .
    "Server=122.111.1.2;".
    "VIRTUALMACHINE=pick0;".
    "PORTNUMBER=1604;".
    "Uid=---;". 
    "Pwd=---;".
    "D3VERSION=710;CONNECTDIALOG=YES";

    if ($con=odbc_connect($connect_string, "MyUser, "MyPasswrd")) { print "ok";}
    else { print "Error";}
```

Thank you for your futur help ! :)

Do I have to install something more ?
what is really Uid, PwD ?
Data base name and it password ?

This is an image of my (not real) Info :
all field are exactly like that :
[D3 Infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOF7p.png)

Answer (score 1):

Create an ODBC Connection

With an ODBC connection, you can connect to any database, on any computer in your network, as long as an ODBC connection is available.

Here is how to create an ODBC connection to a MS Access Database:

1. Open the Administrative Tools icon in your Control Panel.
2. Double-click on the Data Sources (ODBC) icon inside.
3. Choose the System DSN tab.
4. Click on Add in the System DSN tab.
   5.Select the Microsoft Access Driver. Click Finish.
5. In the next screen, click Select to locate the database.
6. Give the database a Data Source Name (DSN).
7. Click OK.

Note that this configuration has to be done on the computer where your web site is located. If you are running Internet Information Server (IIS) on your own computer, the instructions above will work, but if your web site is located on a remote server, you have to have physical access to that server, or ask your web host to to set up a DSN for you to use.

**Connecting to an ODBC**

The **odbc_connect()** function is used to connect to an ODBC data source. The function takes four parameters: the data source name, username, password, and an optional cursor type.

The **odbc_exec()** function is used to execute an SQL statement.
Example

The following example creates a connection to a DSN called northwind, with no username and no password. It then creates an SQL and executes it:

```
$conn=odbc_connect('northwind','','');
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers"; 
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
```

For more details visit this page : http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp.htm